# How do I read from a file in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code to save a file:

```
   private void buttonSaveMapFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string dir = @"mapFile";
            string serializationFile = Path.Combine(dir, "mapFile.bin");
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(serializationFile, FileMode.Create))
            {
                var bFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
                bFormatter.Serialize(stream, _mDataBaseList);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error saving Map file", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
```

However, I'm not sure about how I can read from a file as opposed to writing to one.

I'm new to C# so please don't be mad at me if the answer to the question is obvious :)

Comment: Upload to ftp, http, ... ?

Comment: to local application @WouterHuysentruit

Comment: @YuvalSpiegel "local application" ? What do you mean by that?

Comment: you mean to open (read) the file afterwards in your appliation?

Comment: @Cadburry yes, to read from a custom file on my computer

Comment: Use [BinaryFormatter.Deserialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to load data back from file.

Comment: @YuvalSpiegel To add additional details to the question, please click the `edit` link directly under your question, instead of just leaving them here in the comments. It will make it easier for people to help you and help prevent your question from being closed as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the comments to your question, you mean how do I `read` a file, uploading is different.

To read a file, you will need to use something called a `Stream`. A `Stream` is a `type` that allows you to manage data on the `byte` level. Your file is made up of a series of `bytes`, and because it's a file located on your file system, you would use the `FileStream` `type` to read from it.

```
void Main()
{
    const string filePath = @"test.bin";
    Foo graph = new Foo { Bar = "abc"};

    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    // Write
    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, graph);
    }   


    // Read
    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        object result = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        Foo resultGraph = (Foo)result;

        Console.WriteLine (resultGraph.Bar);
    }

}

[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```